# Can I reset the value of setting keys in SBT shell

Tags: sbt, docker-image

In my**sbt.build file** the following settings can be found

```
val appImageTags = settingKey[String]("Comma separated list of additional tags for app Docker image")

ThisBuild / appImageTags := "36799.amazonaws.com/app"
```

A build task needs a setting key named **appImageTags**. It gives the tag name of the container image which need to pushed to Amazon cloud.

At the moment the image needs to push to a Azure cloud as well, is it possible to change the value of the key in a sbt shell?

**More specifically for what I need to achieve**

Start sbt, change the **appImageTags** value to a new value "36799.azurecr.io.com/app" and build the image so that when I list my images in docker I can found a image tagged with ""36799.azurecr.io.com/app"

Answer (score -1):

Enter the following command in sbt shell is able to solve the issue

```
 appImageTags in ThisBuild ~= { (prev: String) => "36799.azurecr.io.com/app" }
```